# Generate a multiple choice quiz with REST Countries API JSON data using Vanilla Javascript. Randomize order of answers

Tags: javascript, json, api

[image]I'm trying to build a geography game/quiz using the Google Maps API and the REST Countries API as well. I have the Google Maps functionality working along with the REST Countries API as well. What's happening is, on each page refresh, a random country loads and data from the REST Countries API generates (it's hidden so the user will only get hints as to what country it is). The map also pans to the center of the random country(hybrid image only with no country label). This is exactly what I want to happen.

I have a loop in my Javascript pulling countries (answers) for the multiple choice section but it's only pulling from the beginning. Is there a way to randomize the label and insert the correct answer (countryData.name) in there somewhere? I had this working but my code was not dry at all and the first selection was always the right answer. Not sure how to get the loop to pull answers at random either. This is the last thing I need to do before I can start styling and fixing the point system. Sorry, had to hide my Google API key.

```js
const countriesList = document.getElementById("countries");
let gameTitle = document.querySelector(".gameTitle");
let selectedCountry;
let updateScore = document.querySelector(".score");
let guesses = document.querySelector(".wrongAnswers");
let score = 0;
let wrongAnswers = 0;

// Rest Countries
function newQuestion() {
    fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => initialize(data))
    .catch(error => console.log("Error:", error));

function initialize(countriesData) {
    // Define countries
    countries = countriesData;
    // Create an empty string where you add your option value in at random as a string
    let options = "";
    countries.forEach(country => options += `<option value="${country.alpha3Code}">${country.name}</option>`);
    countriesList.innerHTML = options;
    // Random index of one instance of the API call
    countriesList.selectedIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * countriesList.length);
    // Set or return the index of the selected value
    // for display card
    displayCountryInfo(countriesList[countriesList.selectedIndex].value);
    // displayCountryInfo(countriesList.value);
}

function displayCountryInfo(countryByAlpha3Code) {
    let addQuestions = document.querySelector(".question");
    const countryData = countries.find(country => country.alpha3Code === countryByAlpha3Code);
    selectedCountry = countryData.name;
    document.querySelector("#flag-container img").src = countryData.flag;
    // If the flag fails to load, display the country name
    document.querySelector("#flag-container img").alt = `flag of ${countryData.name}`;
    document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = countryData.name;
    document.getElementById("capital").innerHTML = countryData.capital;
    document.getElementById("population").innerHTML = countryData.population.toLocaleString("en-US");
    document.getElementById("currencies").innerHTML = countryData.currencies.filter(c => c.name).map(c => `${c.name} (${c.code})`).join(', ');
    let languages = document.getElementById("languages").innerHTML = countryData.languages.filter(l => l.name).map(l => `${l.name}`).join(', ');
    document.getElementById("region").innerHTML = countryData.region;
    document.getElementById("subregion").innerHTML = countryData.subregion;
    document.getElementById("lat-long").innerHTML = countryData.latlng;
    
    initMap(countryData);

    addQuestions.innerHTML = `I am located in ${countryData.subregion}. There are ${countryData.languages.length} language(s) spoken here: ${languages}. My capital city is ${countryData.capital}. What's my name?`;

    function multipleChoice() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            let $input = document.querySelector('#inputs');
            $input.innerHTML = $input.innerHTML + `<input id='choice${i}' name='countries' type='radio' onchange='getValue(this)' value='${countries[i].name}'/> ${countries[i].name}`;
        }
    }

    multipleChoice();
}
  
// Access Google Maps API
function initMap(country) {
    // Create a variable 
    let myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(country.latlng[0], country.latlng[1]);
    //object literal
    //instantiate map with mapOptions object
    let mapOptions = { 
        center: myLatLng,
        zoom: 5, 
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: 'satellite',
        heading: 90,
        tilt: 45,
        rotateControl: true,
    }

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng
    });

    // Create map
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), mapOptions);
    // Set marker
    marker.setMap(map);
  }

}

newQuestion();

function getValue(element) {
    if (element.value === selectedCountry) {
        score++;
        updateScore.innerHTML = `Score: ${score}`;
        newQuestion();
        if (score === 10) {
            gameTitle.innerHTML = "You Won!";
        }
    } else {
        wrongAnswers++;
        guesses.innerHTML = `Wrong guesses ${wrongAnswers}`
        newQuestion();
        if (wrongAnswers === 3) {
            gameTitle.innerHTML = "Game Over!";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: rgb(51, 45, 45);
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}
  
p {
    padding: 0 2.5rem 2.5rem;
    margin: 0;
}

h3, .score, .wrongAnswers {
    text-align: center;
}

html {
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}

#mapDiv { 
    height: 50%; 
}

#main-container {
    display: none;
    float: right;
    width: 502px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    padding: 0;
  }

#flag-container {
    float: left;
    height: 252px;
    width: 502px;
    background-color: rgb(19, 16, 16);
    border: 10px solid rgb(32, 13, 28);
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 25px rgb(27, 4, 4);
  }

#flag-container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

#quiz-container {
    color: white;
    background: rgb(51, 45, 45);
    overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body { 
        font-size: 12px; 
    }

    #main-container { 
        width: 342px; 
    }  

    #flag-container { 
        height: 172px;
        width: 50%; 
    }  

    #info-container select { 
        font-size: 12px; font-weight: 600; 
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>MapApp Quiz</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">         -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mapDiv"><h1></h1></div>
        <div id="root"></div>

        <div id="flag-container">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </div>

        <div id="main-container">
            <div class="card">
                <div id="info-container">
                    <select id="countries"></select>
                    <p>Country: <span id="country"></span></p>
                    <p>Capital: <span id="capital"></span></p>
                    <p>Population: <span id="population"></span></p>
                    <p>Currencies: <span id="currencies"></span></p>
                    <p>Languages: <span id="languages"></span></p>
                    <p>Region: <span id="region"></span></p>
                    <p>Subregion: <span id="subregion"></span></p>
                    <p>Lat/Long: <span id="lat-long"></span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="quiz-container">
            <h3 class="gameTitle">MapApp Quiz</h3>
                <h5 class="score">Score: 0</h5>
                <h5 class="wrongAnswers">Wrong guesses: 0</h5>
            <p class="question"></p>
            <form id="inputs">
            </form>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API_KEY]"></script>
        <script src="main.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what your countriesData object looks like?

Comment: It's just "selectedCountry = countryData.name" inside the displayCountryInfo function. The country's being randomly generated inside my initialize function with "countriesList.selectedIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * countriesList.length);" and being passed into the displayCountryInfo function.

Comment: I meant the list of countries you pass to initialize(). It's not clear to me what output should look like.

Comment: I'm trying to post one object but it takes up too many lines so I'm sending you the link to the entire object in JSON. https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it's not clear to me how you're selecting the "correct" answer, but let's assume you have one country that is the answer and then the list of all countries. You could make a list of 4 random countries plus the correct country like so:

```
function generateAnswers(answer, allCountries) {
    let wrongCountries = allCountries.filter(country => country.alpha3Code !== answer.alpha3Code); 

    const countOfAnswers = 5;
    const positionOfCorrectAnswer = Math.floor(Math.random() * (countOfAnswers + 1));
    const answers = []; 
    for(let i=0; i< countOfAnswers; i++) {
       if (i === positionOfCorrectAnswer) {
          answers.push(answer);
       } else {
         let randomAnswer = wrongCountries[Math.floor(Math.random() * wrongCountries.length)]; 
          wrongCountries = wrongCountries.filter(country => country.alpha3Code !== randomAnswer.alpha3Code); 
          answers.push({ name: randomAnswer.name, alpha3Code: randomAnswer.alpha3Code } );
       } 
    }
    return answers;
};
```

Ok, so this function should return you an array of 5 countries including the right answer and 4 random wrong answers.  You can call this in your code that builds the options and build the HTML from it, rather than using the full list of countries.

Comment: Paul, thanks! It's kind of working. I took your function and added my multiple choice function inside of it so now the answers are being generated at random. Your function is pushing random countries into the multiple choice segment but I can't get the correct answer to show. I can console.log it and see that your function is generating the correct answer when I push (country, countries) in as arguments. country being the correct country and countries being the entire list of countries. Any idea how I can adjust this to show the correct country in the mult choice list? I'll keep working on it

Comment: Paul, what you gave me is fine. I just have to figure out how push the right country in as an object in the argument. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Daisy where/how do you currently determine which country is the right answer?

Comment: Also, I'd recommend reading up on "single responsibility principle".  You're frequently going to find things are easier to create and maintain if you keep each function doing one thing.  So, one function that just figures out the list of options, another one that creates the HTML for it.

Comment: Inside my initialize function, the line '    countriesList.selectedIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * countriesList.length);' chooses the country index at random. That is then passed to the displayCountryInfo function and selectedCountry will display the name. Thank you! I will definitely read into single responsibility principle.

Comment: It works now. I added 'answers.push({ name: countryData.name, alpha3Code: countryData.alpha3Code });' to get the correct answer. I just need to figure out how to stop the loop from continuing to add answers on top of answers each time a question is answered.

Comment: Each time you get a new question, you should generate a new list of answers for that question, and completely new HTML generated from it.